# QML StackView Focus

Tags: qml

I recently refactored some code where different pages in an application were controlled via StackLayout. I changed this to be controlled by StackView to conserve resources. Everything works fine except for one page that takes USB Keyboard input. It is non-responsive to the input in the StackView control, but works as it should under StackLayout control. I am working under the assumption that this is due to a Focus issue. Can anyone help me out here?

main.qml

```
 StackView {
        id: layout
        initialItem:splash{}
        anchors.fill: parent
        onCurrentItemChanged: {
             if (currentItem ) {

               console.log(layout.currentItem)
                currentItem.forceActiveFocus()
               console.log(layout.activeFocus)

             }
        }
        Item {
            id: getStackView
             function get(){ //this is called in a timer above


                 if( Number(layoutFile.readCheck()) === 1){

                     layout.replace(Qt.resolvedUrl("Login.qml") , StackView, StackView.Immediate)

                 }
            }
         }
  }
```

Login.qml

```
   Rectangle{
        id: logbox
        color: "#EFEBE9"
        radius: 2
        width: 225
        height: 30
        border.color: "black"


        x:300

        y:220
        property string placeholderText: "   "
        TextInput {
            width: 225
            height: 30
            focus: true

            text: logbox.placeholderText
            signal qmlSignal(string msg)

            onAccepted: {

                console.log("msg="+text)
                fileStuff.save(text);

            }
          }

    }
```

Tried forcing active focus, but that didn't work.

Comment: Try reading the root Window's [activeFocusItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#activeFocusItem-prop) property to see what item actually has focus. I often use `onActiveFocusItemChanged: { console.log("Focus is on: " + activeFocusItem); console.trace(); }` to help me track these things down.

Comment: JarMan- I took your suggestion and looked at the root Windows activefocusItem.  I got this :                                                                                                               qml:  Current Item changed to:  QQuickRectangle(0x1e39af0)
qml: Main Window Focus Item: QQuickRectangle(0x1e39af0)
qml: current item focus: true
It appears to be changing the active focus correctly. Now I'm really confused.

Comment: So you are setting focus to Login.qml which is a Rectangle, but I assume you want to drive focus deeper to a child of that rectangle (i.e. the TextInput), right?

Comment: For your `Login.qml` you should declare `Component.onCompleted: Qt.callLater(textInput.forceActiveFocus)`. There shouldn't be any need to do anything at the StackLayout level.

Comment: JarMan-That is correct.

Comment: OKAY it's working now. Thanks to the questions asked I realized I needed to pass the focus further down.